# Pyttsx3 not compiling with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, text-to-speech, buildozer, pyttsx3

I want to use pyttsx3 in my Kivy Application. But when I compiled it with buildozer, the app starts and stops suddenly after showing the loading sign. Does Kivy have any special TTS module? How to fix this?

Comment: I suggest posting the logcat of your app. Otherwise we can only guess the issues. I, however, doubt, that the issue is with the installation. I checked, and the module in question is written in pure python. So, Buildozer should just compile it without an issue.

Comment: @NameKhan72 I use Google Colab for Linux environment. Did you mean that I must also `pip install pyttsx3` before converting to app. I thought that it automatically installs the necessary modules given in requirements section in the buildozer.spec file.

Comment: No, you're correct in thinking, that you do not have to install the package manually. Buildozer does that automatically. Any way we can get the logcat?